# ValueError: "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous" when using IF and ELSE where conditions are from different columns

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

How to solve ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Below is my code:

```
d = {'color':['White', 'Gray', 'Black'],
     'percent':[50, 30, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

if (df['color'] == 'White') & (df['percent'] >= 90.0):
    print('Page is still loading')
else:
    print("Page load successfully")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\***.py", line 1527, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

print what in the if and else condition

Comment: `df['color'] == 'White'` The error is telling you that this condition is ambiguous.  `df['color']` is a column containing _many_ values.  Some of those values may be equal to "White", and some may not.  It makes no sense to ask "is this column equal to White?"

Comment: Understood. What will you recommend for me to get my desired output? Printing the message if meet the condition

Comment: You haven't said what your desired output is...